# Take value of <a> into <div class>?

Tags: web-crawler, html-parsing

I'm looking for a way to crawl in php the value of a `<a>` that does not have a class or id, but that is inside a `<div>` that has a class.

Here is the html code to crawler:

```
<div class="myclass">
    <a href="/to">value to crawl</a>
</div>
```

Here is the line of my php code (unsuccessfully):

```
preg_match_all('<div class=\"myclass\"><a>(.*)<\/a><\/div>', $myhtml, $match);
```

thank for your response :)

Comment: Consider using `xpath` instead `preg_match`: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parser would be a much better solution:

```
$html = '<div class="myclass">
    <a href="/to">value to crawl</a>
</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$a_s = $xpath->query('*/div[contains(@class, \'myclass\')]/a');
foreach($a_s as $a) {
    if(empty($a->getAttribute('class')) && empty($a->getAttribute('id'))) {
        echo $a->nodeValue;
    } else {
        echo 'not';
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/YmCAv

The answer to your question though would be:

1. `<a>` does not exist in your string
2. Regexs need delimiters in PHP
3. `><` also doesn't exist in your string
4. Forward slashes and double quotes dont need to be escaped unless they are being used, they have no special meaning in regex. (in answer below I am using forward slash as delimiter so I kept it escaped)

So to correct your regex it would be:

```
/<div class="myclass">\s*<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>\s*<\/div>/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0tfwDu/1/

Comment: thank for your response.  However, an error message appears with this method and I can not get to the case ... "PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Attribute class redefined in Entity, line: 1593 in /Users/etc/index.php on line 54"

Comment: What is the HTML in that instance?

Comment: it is a text file, result of a crawl with curl, and open with this : $html = file_get_contents('file_of_webpage.txt');

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of HTML that reproduces the error?